# mysql query user stay in same city and same country

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users thas has the following fields

```
id, name, city id, country id
```

How can I select users who are in the same city and same country?

**Example**

```
id   name cityid countryid
1    ram   1       2
2    sam   5       2
3    bil   1       2
4    roy   4       6
5    bin   5       2
7    abu   7       5
```

What is the `MySQL` query so I can fetch only user id 1 and 3 having same city id 1 and country id 2
and user id 2 and 5 for same city if 5 and country id 2.

Comment: Are you going to specify the city ID and country ID each time, or do you want all sets of users with same city and country IDs?

Comment: show us what u have tried so far...

Comment: i like to show users who are same city and same country

Comment: in your select query on your where clause cityid = countryid

Comment: Maybe redesigning your db to allow a city only to exist in one country would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cityid, countryid, GROUP_CONCAT(name) names
FROM users
GROUP BY cityid, countryid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table onto itself, and ask which city & country is the same. Be sure to specify that the userid's must be different in your where clause, because every user lives in the same city & country as itself.

```
SELECT u1.id, u2.id, u1.name, u2.name, u1.cityid, u2.cityid /*or whatever fields you want*/
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2
WHERE u1.id < u2.id
and u1.cityid = u2.cityid
and u1.countryid= u2.countryid
```

Comment: I would use `u1.id < u2.id`. Otherwise you'll get two rows for each pair.

Answer (score 0):

The same country would be like this:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT countryid FROM users GROUP BY countryid HAVING count(*) > 1) AS countries USING (countryid)
```